# Trying to run different functions based on user input

Tags: python

```
def teamEnter():
    for x in range (4):
        tnames.append(input("Please enter a team name:"))
    print(tnames)
    tevent1()
#This loops 4 times and asks you to enter 4 team names
    
def individualEnter():
    for x in range (20):
        inames.append(input("Please enter an individuals name:"))
    print(inames)
    ievent1()
#This loops 20 times and asks you to enter 20 individual names
    

def intro():
    inp = input("Would you like to hold a tournament for teams or individuals: ")
    # Asks the user to enter as a team or individual
    print (' ')
    TeamOrIndividual = str(inp)
    if inp == "Individuals":
        individualEnter()
    elif inp =="Teams":
        teamEnter()
#This is the initial home page where you choose between teams or individuals
intro()

def tevent1():
    print("This is the relay race event")
    
def ievent1():
    print("This is the tug of war event")
```

I want to be able to run the tevent1 when the user inputs 'Teams' at the start and the ievent1 when the user inputs 'Individuals' at the start.

How do i do this?

Should i use an IF statement in the intro function or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: 1. Post your code as text, not as an image.  2. What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: Please, [provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is `firstTeamPlace` a `list`?

Comment: You wrote "firstTeamPlace" array (I imagine you mean list), but then you check if it is a string. Do you want to compare the last element? Also, why don't you pass any variable to your function?
Please, provide more details about your code.

Comment: At first glance, this code seems like it will do what you want.  So, what is the problem?

Comment: Mixing strings like `"1"` with ints like `4` isn't good design. Why not have all your arrays be arrays of ints? You could use `int(input(...` rather than just `input(...`

Comment: `firstTeamPlace == "1"` (or any other condition) will never be true because it's a _list_, not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have what you want to do in a faster and more flexible way:

```
#Some preparation. You can do it manually or with another function

tnames = ['team 1', 'team 2', 'team 3', 'team 4', 'team 5'] 
teamsPlaces = [] # This is for where the teams placed for each event, 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc
teamsTotals = [] # This is where the scores are added to make a final score for each team

#Here we prepare the final scores, with everyone starting from 0
for team in range(len(tnames)):
    teamsTotals.append(0)

def tevent1():
    print("This is the relay race event")
    print("Please enter the where each team placed next to their name (1-4)")
    eventTeamsPlaces = []
    for i in range(len(tnames)):
        teamPos = input(tnames[i])
        eventTeamsPlaces.append(teamPos) #for each event, you will have a list of places
        teamsTotals[i] = teamsTotals[i] + (len(tnames) - int(teamPos))
        
    teamsPlaces.append(eventTeamsPlaces) #and the list of places is appended to the list of places for all the events
    print(teamsTotals)
tevent1()
```

so that at the end, after two events, your outputs are:

```
teamsPlaces = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']]
teamsTotals = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

end if you want to have the list of the places for the event number 2 you can just use `teamsPlaces[1]` which is `['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']`

With this approach, you can use this simple function for all the events, without any limit for the number of teams and the number of events.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your logic:

```
def firstTeamPoints():
    firstTeamTotal.append(5 - int(firstTeamPlace))
```

If it turns out to be more complicated, you can use a map:

```
m = {
    "1": 4,
    "2": 3,
    "3": 2,
    "4": 1,
}
def firstTeamPoints():
    firstTeamTotal.append(m[firstTeamPlace])
```

Comment: The firstTeamTotal array still isnt being appended